# Altium: Access Database Library - Only "Library Ref" Appears In Lib Panel

Tags: altium, library

Over the past couple of days I have been experimenting with Altium's Access database library feature and have run into an issue. I have a test database and Altium seems to be reading from it without a problem, but in the Libraries panel when I try to go add a part, the part number field does not show up. Only the Library Ref column appears:

[image]

The tutorial I am following shows other fields (namely "Part Number"):

[image]

The above image is what I am expecting (except I would like to be able to choose which fields appear). What am I missing here? What tells Altium which fields to show in that panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was easy -- I had right-clicked in the panel a dozen times and somehow still missed it. When you right-click in the panel there is an option to "Select columns":

[image]

The window that pops up allows you to select which columns are displayed:

[image]